# How does the multiplayer in Hill Climb Racing 2 actually work?

Tags: hill-climb-racing-2

While playing Hill Climb Racing 2, you face a series of races against other online drivers, or at least I think they are, but you can pause the race and they pause too. Am I racing other players' ghosts of their best times? How does the game decide who I should race? How does the ranking system work? Are other players racing against my ghosts?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're racing against downloaded copies of other people trying to do the run.

In order to prevent unfortunate lag, or unfortunate lagging, (as well as allowing you to pause the game), the other players have their attempts of the map downloaded onto the game before being played, like ghosts.

I couldn't find any information to confirm or deny if it's a player's "best" times, however given how frequently I come across other players who actually don't make it to the end, as well as the fact that often (in the higher leagues) it takes longer to find a match, I do believe you are playing against players who are online and playing that cup at that given moment (or have done so very recently).

To answer if you're also in those matches - I presume not, as I've never seen someone time out mid-match, or leave mid-match, so presumably once you've completed a cup your go is uploaded and can be used for the next *x* minutes to play against other players.

Comment: Based on comments in Reddit by their customer representative, they are complete race ghosts of other players, selected based on your latest performances. So if you finish all 3 races of Cup A in 30 seconds, 25 seconds and 25 seconds, the next time you play that Cup, you will be picked a group of driver ghosts where the other cars are also finishing it in around 30+25+25 times. There is some level of leeway, so normally you wouldn't race "unbeatable" cars. It can sometimes happen that one car in the Cup finishes in say 19+15+18 - far faster than you - but it is rare.